# Google Maps drag and dragend event listeners won't work if marker created by click event listener

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just a noob trying to learn, I came out with a problem that when I try to create marker with click event, drag and dragend event listeners won't work. Whereas when created by default these work.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">         </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22,79);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Default Marker',
        draggable:true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Click Generated Marker',
        draggable:true
        });
    }
);

google.maps.event.addListener(
    marker,
    'drag',
    function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = this.position.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = this.position.lng();
        //alert('drag');
    });


google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = this.position.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = this.position.lng();
        alert('Drag end');
    });


  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>

Lat: <input type="text" id="lat"><br>
Lng: <input type="text" id="lng">

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

What you probably want to do is change the reference in your event listeners, from *this* to the event itself.

Then you need to add separate event listeners for your new marker at the same time as you create it.  I'd suggest simply having one function which takes input arguments for the latlng, title, and anything else you need.  And it then creates the marker and any event listeners required.

```js
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22,79);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    addMarker(myLatlng, 'Default Marker', map);

    map.addListener('click',function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng, 'Click Generated Marker', map);
    );
}

function handleEvent(event) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
}

function addMarker(latlng,title,map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            draggable:true
    });

    marker.addListener('drag', handleEvent);
    marker.addListener('dragend', handleEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zoom:25,
        title: title,
        draggable:true,
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: info 
  });
infowindow.open(map,marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(event) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Latitude: ' + event.latLng.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + event.latLng.lng()
      });
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) 
        {
    document.getElementById('lat').value =event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value =event.latLng.lng();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Latitude: ' + event.latLng.lat() + '<br>Longitude:'+`event.latLng.lng()
      });
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to future readers if you would elaborate on your code

Comment: @Vishal in my case above both events not triggered can you tell me why?

Answer (score 4):

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      draggable:true,
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Try creating the marker like this .

Comment: Thank's @krikara for such a quick reply. markers do get created but drag and dragend still wont work.

Comment: Don't use your code, use mines. Those last two listeners you use don't work. ALl you need is draggable true. Although I can't run this code right now and it isnt exactly correct, so maybe you can tweak it a little.

Comment: I am using your code only. I wanted dragend event to get the location stored of the marker in database. I added dragend event in your code but its not getting fired.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your intentions. Sorry. I can't really experiment with code right now, so perhaps this will help. (someone else's code)
http://jsfiddle.net/ABqMH/8/

Comment: This code generates an marker by default which fires drag and dragend event so does my above code. But the problem again generates when a marker is created by click event, darg and dragend event wont fire then.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your efforts.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but the above answer is pretty sweet.