# How to create route on a google map using KML exported data?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I used Google Map engine to create a route on the map with marker and linestring across the markers(link: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=z0-DS05yFIOY.kk3gqtVGUw90 ). I then exported the data in a (kml) file. All i want to do now is create a dynamic route using the below information such as Lat/Long coordinates when someone clicks a button on my website. I am building a mobile app using HTML5,CSS3 and JavaScript. My initial idea was to save the coordinates information in a database using KML parser to parse the KML file. Once i have the coordinate saved i can call them from my javascript code ? Not sure it that is a solution to my problem

```
<name>UFV To Peardonville and South Fraser   </name>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#icon-seq-0-0</styleUrl>
            <name>Stop 1- University of the Fraser Valley</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-122.28257417678833,49.02859706469696,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#icon-seq-0-1</styleUrl>
            <name>Stop 2 - Marshall and McCallum</name>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-122.29326009750366,49.03969659484145,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

<Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#line-FF8277-7</styleUrl>
            <name>Line 8</name>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>0</tessellate>
                <coordinates>-122.28205919265747,49.02870961988958,0.0 -122.281973361969,49.03145307396853,0.0 -122.29304552078247,49.031270181736296,0.0 -122.29298114776611,49.033211618811904,0.0 -122.29280948638916,49.03466061304994,0.0 -122.29257345199585,49.035012304315345,0.0 -122.29332447052002,49.0358563532078,0.0 -122.29334592819214,49.03985132363843,0.0 -122.2934103012085,49.04564627375429,0.0 -122.29032039642334,49.0456181445595,0.0 -122.29032039642334,49.0474605732066,0.0 -122.2902774810791,49.049049788878406,0.0 -122.29180097579956,49.04906385250716,0.0 -122.29519128799438,49.04933106069776,0.0 -122.30310916900635,49.05028737298155,0.0 -122.30478286743164,49.050498321744364,0.0 -122.30437517166138,49.05023111982696,0.0 -122.30448246002197,49.04684174982452,0.0 -122.30677843093872,49.04696832796101,0.0 -122.30982542037964,49.049387314870685,0.0 -122.30997562408447,49.05084990102674,0.0</coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a route between two markers in Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854072/how-to-draw-a-route-between-two-markers-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: [example with your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_directions_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_20140318_route.kml)

Comment: Hi geocodezip can you please explain to me how did you create that ? i visited the webpage but can you tell me how did you draw that ?

Comment: is there like a tutorial or link i can follow that will be of great help ?