# How can I display selected city of combo box in the google map on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <select v-model="selectedCity">
                <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <h4>Selected city key: {{selectedCity}}</div>
        </div>
    `,
    data: {
        cities: [
            {id: 1, name: "Manchester"},
            {id: 2, name: "London"},
            {id: 3, name: "Liverpool"},
            {id: 4, name: "Leicester"},
            {id: 5, name: "Southampton"}
        ],
        selectedCity: ""
    }
});
```

Demo like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3x0z3vzk/38/

I want if I click a city, it will display the city in the google map

For example, I select London on the combobox, it will display London on the google map

How can I do it?

Comment: Add geocoordinates and place a balloon on the map

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I took so long to see your request/comment. Anyway, I'm glad it was not a problem I was late because the accepted answer is pretty good! I definitely vouch for it! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough to help you move forward in the right direction.

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/pojy5htn/12/

e.g.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div>
            <select v-model="selectedCity">
                <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <h4>Selected city key: {{selectedCity}}</div>
        </div>
    `,
  data: {
    cities: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Manchester",
        lat: 53.480759,
        lng: -2.242631
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "London",
        lat: 51.507351,
        lng: -0.127758
      }
    ],
    selectedCity: ""
  },
  mounted() {
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 5,
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
  },
  created() {
    this.map = null;
    this.mark = null;
  },
  watch: {
    selectedCity(v) {
      // get the selecte city
      const city = this.cities.filter(obj => obj.id === v).pop();

      //this remove the previous marker on the map
      if (this.mark) this.mark.setMap(null);

      // set map center to the location
      this.map.setCenter({
        lat: city.lat,
        lng: city.lng
      });

      // create a marker for the city and assign it to `this.map`
      this.mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: city.lat,
          lng: city.lng
        },
        map: this.map,
        draggable:true,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I want to ask. How can I shift icon location in the google map?

Comment: @SuccessMan if you mean moving the marker, this is how `marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 ) );`

Comment: @SuccessMan um.. where to add it depends on the function that you wanna perform? I don't what is it that you are trying to do

Comment: Try to see your jsfiddle. I want the marker can move. In your jsfiddle, the marker cannot move

Comment: @SuccessMan what you want is to called `draggable`. it can be done just by adding `draggable:true,` to the marker init function. see the updates

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I want to ask again. How can I get latitude, longitude and address after I drag the marker?

Comment: @SuccessMan `this.mark.getPosition().lat()` `this.mark.getPosition().lng()` ...actually you could easily google these yourself and learn something new along the way =]

Comment: Yes. I had try it. But i'm still confused. So I ask here

Comment: How can I get address? I try `console.log(this.mark.getPosition)`. But I don'f find address. There only lat & long

Comment: @SuccessMan this explains it pretty well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12829342/5599288

Comment: Okay. I will try it. I want to ask again. How can I get lat & long after I drag the marker. I'm still confused to make the script

Comment: @SuccessMan you gotta use a drag event listener. for e.g. `this.mark.addListener('dragend', function(event) { this.mark.getPosition().lat(); // ... });`. There is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391164/5599288

Comment: References you provide using javascript. Whereas I use vue.js

Comment: @SuccessMan Vue is javascript too =] You can make it work inside Vue

Comment: Hey, man, great answer. Using a watch like that, I believe, it is really a good way to go!